# PHP exec() function and escapeshellarg function still allowing command injection

Tags: php, unix

i have been trying to fix a vulnerablity where input from a user is passed through to the php exec function. The input is sanitized using escapeshellarg but it seems like it still allows code to be injected and executed. I tested this using Burp Suite's collaborator functionality by doing a nslookup.

I am unable to provide the exact code but below is a pretty close example. Can someone please shed some light why this works?

```
$input = 'filename$(whoami).pdf';

$cmd = 'rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($input) . ' 2>&1';
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: `exec($input);` - There you execute the unescaped input instead of the command with the escaped input . Also, _"I am unable to provide the exact code but below is a pretty close example"_ isn't helpful. If you want to prove an issue like this, you need to give us an _exact_ example so we can verify your actual case. If you've verified it yourself, then you should be able to give us the actual input/code you used?

Comment: Hi @ M.Eriksson - Apologies i had an error in the question. The $cmd is what is executed by the code.

Also, i verified this using Burp suite by intercepting the request and modifing the files "name" attribute. I used Burp collaborator for this.